# Dynamically filter List with Predicate

Tags: java, guava, predicate

I have the following list of Strings:

> {"New York","London","Paris","Berlin","New York"}

I am trying to use the Guava Library and I want to filter this list in such a way that I will get only the strings which will equal to a string that I will provide. If I had a fixed value let's say "New York" I would do the following:

```
Predicate<String> myCity = new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override public boolean apply(String city) {
        return city == "New York";
    }               
};
```

But what if I want the return statement to be something like this :

> return city == myStringVariable

Can I give the argument for the city to the Predicate or combine two predicates somehow ?

Comment: User `equals()` for `String`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either you use a final String or subclass of Predicate :

```
final String testStr = textbox.getText(); //for example
Predicate<String> myCity = new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override public boolean apply(String city) {
        return city.equals(testStr);
    }               
};
```

or

```
public class CityPredicate implements Predicate<String>{
    String cityName;
    public CityPredicate(String cityName){
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }
    @Override public boolean apply(String city) {
        return city.equals(cityName);
    } 
}
//Use example :
Predicate<String> myCity = new CityPredicate("New York");
```

And as @Sotirios Delimanolis told you, always compare String with equals()

EDIT : example with Frank Pavageau's solution :
Given your class :

```
public class City{
    String cityName;
    public City(String cityName){
        this.cityName=cityName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof String){
            return cityName.equals(obj);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

List<City> cities =  Lists.newArrayList(new City("New York"),new City("Chicago"));
Predicate<String> myCityPredicate = Predicates.equalTo("New York");
final List<City> res = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(cities , myCityPredicate));
//res.size() will be 1 and containing only your City("New York")
//To check whether it is present you can do :
final boolean isIn = Predicates.in(cities).apply("New York");
```

Comment: `City` objects should only be equal to other `City` objects, or you'll break the `equals` contract and invite seriously unpleasant messiness.

Comment: What if I testStr keeps changing while going through a foreach loop. You end up creating new predicates for each new testStr? Is there a way to create a single predicate in case which I mentioned?

Answer (score 8):

Guava provides a number of really generic `Predicate`s, via the [`Predicates`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/base/Predicates.html) helper class.

To filter on equality (be it for a `String` or any other object), it provides the [`equalTo()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html#equalTo%28T%29) predicate:

```
Predicate<String> myCity = Predicates.equalTo(myStringVariable);
```

---

Update to answer a question in the comments: how to filter when the list is not of `String`s but of objects which have a `String` property.

You have several options, depending on what you already have:

1. Use imperative code

   For a one-time use, unless you use Java 8, it's a bit verbose to use the functional constructs. See the [FunctionalExplained](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained) page in the wiki.

   ```
   private List<SomeObject> filterOnMyCity(List<SomeObject> list,
                                           String value) {
       List<SomeObject> result = new ArrayList<>();
       for (SomeObject o : list) {
           if (value.equals(o.getMyCity())) {
               result.add(o);
           }
       }
       return result;
   }
   ```
2. Use an ad-hoc predicate

   ```
   class MyCityPredicate implements Predicate<SomeObject> {
        private final String value;

        public MyCityPredicate(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean apply(@Nullable SomeObject input) {
            return input != null && value.equals(input.getPropertyX());
        }
   }

   return FluentIterable.from(list)
           .filter(new MyCityPredicate(myStringVariable))
           .toList();
   ```
3. Use an existing `Function`

   ```
   class MyCityFunction implements Function<SomeObject, String> {
        @Override
        public String apply(@Nullable SomeObject input) {
            return input == null ? null : input.getPropertyX();
        }
   }

   return FluentIterable.from(list)
           .filter(Predicates.compose(
                   Predicates.equalTo(myStringVariable),
                   new MyCityFunction()))
           .toList();
   ```

However, I wouldn't override `equals()` as mentioned in the comments, it could be too specific to say that 2 instances of `SomeObject` are equals just because one of their properties is. It doesn't scale if you need to filter on 2 different properties in different contexts.

If you have Java 8, the code becomes much more compact using lambda expressions, and you can directly use the `Stream` API anyway so you don't need Guava *for that*.

Comment: @Frank Pavageau I suppose you can't use this if you have a list of objects which have the myCity variable as a property, or is it possible ?

Comment: It is if you override the equals method of your class (from doc : `Returns a predicate that evaluates to true if the object being tested equals() the given target or both are null.`)

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the predicate by closing over a some other variable

```
final String cityName = "New York";
Predicate<String> myCity = new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override public boolean apply(String city) {
        return city.equals(cityName);
    }               
};
```

**Note how I compare strings with their `equals` method rather than  the `==` reference equality operator. See below for why.**

[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)